# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this error that every time I make a change to my code it blocks me then it adds an iframe to my code which blocks me from using my app, I haven't changed anything in my packages.

```
**<iframe style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; z-index: 2147483647;"></iframe>**
```

Then in the console I have this error each time I save my code :

```
VM17348:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at 4043 (<anonymous>:2:13168)
at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
at 8048 (<anonymous>:2:9496)
at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
at 8641 (<anonymous>:2:1379)
at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
at <anonymous>:2:315627
at <anonymous>:2:324225
at <anonymous>:2:324229
at e.onload (index.js:1:1)
```

I am using react 17.0.1 and react-dom 17.0.1 and react-scripts 4.0.3.
I even tried to upgrade to react 18 and react-scripts 5 but nothing changes.

**Thank you very much for your help**

Comment: yes   Thank you, i delete package-lock and node_modules and i add  in package json "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },